# Getting HTTP headers with URLSessionDownloadDelegate

Tags: swift, nsurlsession

How would I go about getting the headers from the server to check it the status code is `200`, `404`, etc.?

I have a delegate class:

```
class DownloadDelegate : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate, URLSessionTaskDelegate {
    // Implementations of delegate methods:
    [...]didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL[...]
    [...]didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64[...]
}
```

But I'm not sure where I can extract the headers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`urlSession(_:downloadTask:didFinishDownloadingTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessiondownloaddelegate/1411575-urlsession) provides you the headers.

The parameter `downloadTask` has an attribute `.response` of type [`URLResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlresponse).

Assuming that you are using HTTP/HTTPS, this can be casted to [`HTTPURLResponse`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/httpurlresponse).

> Whenever you make an HTTP request, the NSURLResponse object you get back is actually an instance of the HTTPURLResponse class.
>
> (*Source: API Reference of URLResponse*)

`HTTPURLResponse` has properties to get the status code (`statusCode`) and all header fields as `[AnyHashable: Any]` (`allHeaderFields`).

### Example:

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    guard let response = downloadTask.response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
        return //something went wrong
    }

    let status = response.statusCode
    let completeHeader = response.allHeaderFields
}
```